# copy assignament isn't called in function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

in my book (programming principles and practice) there is an exercise in which functions are called in order to see how constructor and destructor works
this is the class used:

```
struct X {
    int val;

    void out(const string& s, int nv) { cerr << this << "->" << s << ": " << val << " (" << nv << ")\n"; }

    X() { out("X()", 0); val = 0; }                   // default constructor 
    X(int v) { val = v; out("X(int)", v); }
    X(const X& x) { val = x.val; out("X(X&) ", x.val); }     // copy constructor 
    X& operator=(const X& a)           // copy assignment                    
    {
        out("X::operator=()", a.val); val = a.val; return *this;
    }
    ~X() { out("~X()", 0); }
};
```

this is the function i don't understand:

```
X copy2(X a) {
 X aa = a; 
 return aa; 
}
```

this is the call:

```
loc2 = copy2(loc);
```

and this is the output:

```
0018F6B4->X(X&) : 5 (5) 
0018F690->X(X&) : 5 (5)
0018F8D0->X(X&) : 5 (5)
0018F690->~X(): 5 (0)
0018F6B4->~X(): 5 (0)
0018FBA4->X::operator=(): 5 (5)
0018F8D0->~X(): 5 (0)
```

but should be like this?

```
0018F6B4->X(X&) : 5 (5) //here is copied the argument in temp
0018F690->X::operator=(): 5 (5) //here is called copy assignament X aa = a
0018F8D0->X(X&) : 5 (5) //here is copied the return value aa
0018F690->~X(): 5 (0) //here is destroyed aa
0018F6B4->~X(): 5 (0) //here is destroyed temp of argument
0018FBA4->X::operator=(): 5 (5) //copy assignament
0018F8D0->~X(): 5 (0) //destroye the temp of return
```

and another question why this

```
X& ref_to(X& a) { return a; }
X& r = ref_to(loc);    // call by reference and return   
doesn't print nothing?
```

Comment: `X aa = a;` is copy-construction, not copy assignment.

Comment: For the first question you should show the code the calls copy2 .  Some of the output lines are from the calling function.

Comment: The second question doesn't make sense. To avoid confusion I suggest posting a separate question for the second question, , and include [compilable code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: why X aa = a doesn't call copy assigament operator? it's strange?

Comment: @tuttomax because you're creating new X object called aa, which should be a copy of a. Copy assignment operator would be called if you assign new object to already existing one. Example X aa; aa = a; //here copy assignment is called.

Comment: @tuttomax `X aa = a;` is copy construction, not copy assignment. You are thinking it is equivilent to `X aa; aa = a;` but it is actually more eqivilent to `X aa(a);` instead. A `=` used during construction is just syntax sugar to make it easier on humans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `copy2` function's

```
X aa = a;
```

is not a declaration with assignment: that doesn't exist in C++.

It's a declaration with copy initialization, which in C++03 would always use the copy constructor -- unless the copying was optimized away by the compiler.

In C++11 and later, depending on the type and the initializer, it can use the move constructor instead.